# Dynamic Stable identifiers in Scala Pattern Match

Tags: scala, parsing, functional-programming, pattern-matching, stable-identifier

Using Scala, is there any way to dynamically construct a list patterns to be pattern matched against?

For example, suppose I'm using **stable identifiers** to *parse* a list of Strings, like this:

```
def matchingAndDispatch(xs: List[String])= {
  case `namespace` :: value :: `elementTerminator` :: rest => {
    // Do Something...
  }
  case `openBracket` :: rest => {
    // Do Something Else...
  }
  case `closeBracket` :: `elementTerminator` :: rest => {
    // Or perhaps something else...
  } 
}
```

Now, suppose there are going to be a lot of case clauses and I wanted the ability to store them in a collection of some sort that could be changed at runtime - not necessarily the patterns themselves, but the collection of patterns could be changed. I've made up the imaginary class MatchClause in the code below to explain more or less what I have in mind - basically traverse a collection of pattern(i.e. Match Clauses) and match one at a time:

```
def matchingAndDispatch(xs: List[String], matchingClauses:List[MatchClause])= {
  if(!matchingClauses.empty){
    case matchingClauses.head => {
    // Do Something...
    }
    case _ =>  matchingAndDispatch(xs, matchingClause.tail) 
    }
  }else throw new Error("no match")
```

Is there anything in the Scala API that would serve this purpose? I haven't found anything. Or perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way?

Comment: From the looks of it you might be ok just using Parser Combinators. Simply define the context free grammar and Scala will do the rest for you. Are you actually matching a `List[String]` or do you have a more complex structure in real code? In either case identifier names are not very relevant here because all elements are of the same type (not an HList). Finally a note of caution - you have to put cases with more matching elements at the top, otherwise Scala will never match your case 3 from example because case 2 matches it as well - backticks help here to match specific values, but be carefu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
val `namespace` = "namespace"
val `elementTerminator` = "elementTerminator"
val `openBracket` = "openBracket"
val `closeBracket` = "closeBracket"

// list of partial functions from list of strings to string:    
val patterns = List[PartialFunction[List[String], String]](
  { case `namespace` :: value :: `elementTerminator` :: rest => "case1" },
  { case `openBracket` :: rest => "case2" },
  { case `closeBracket` :: `elementTerminator` :: rest => "case3" })

def matchingAndDispatch(xs: List[String], patterns: List[PartialFunction[List[String], String]]): String = {
  patterns.find(_.isDefinedAt(xs)).map(_(xs)).getOrElse("unknown")
}
```

Test:

```
matchingAndDispatch(List("namespace", "somevalue", "elementTerminator"), patterns)
> case1

matchingAndDispatch(List("namespace", "somevalue", "elementTerminator", "more"), patterns)
> case1

matchingAndDispatch(List("namespace", "somevalue", "not_terminator", "more"), patterns)
> unknown
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a stable identifier within a local scope. That is, you can write

```
val hd = matchingClauses.head
xs match {
  case `hd` => ???
}
```